# Getting to scholars table between a range of age from date column?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a criteria to display the age within the age range.Using this code, its working fine but the calculation is base on year only.It might be good if the calculation includes the day also to make it more accurate.

```
database Scholar
scholar_id      scholar_birthday         
1               1991-12-19            
2               1990-01-19            
3               2000-03-19            
4               1992-21-19            
5               1991-12-19            
6               2000-10-12            
7               2001-12-23            
8               2009-12-19            

public function ListOrgaScholar($ship_id)
{
    $ship = Scholarship::find($ship_id);
    $ship_age_from = $ship->ship_age_from;
    $ship_age_to = $ship->ship_age_to;

    $scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery()->select('*');

    $scholars->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,scholars.scholar_birthday,CURDATE())'),array($ship_age_from,$ship_age_to));

    $scholars = $scholars->get();


    dd($scholars);
}
result of dd($scholars)
Collection {#268 ▼
#items: array:3 [▼
0 => Scholar {#270 ▶}
1 => Scholar {#275 ▶}
2 => Scholar {#303 ▶}
]
}
```

In the second code:
It generates an error...

```
public function ListOrgaScholar($ship_id)
{
    $ship = Scholarship::find($ship_id);
    $ship_age_from = $ship->ship_age_from;
    $ship_age_to = $ship->ship_age_to;

    $scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery()->select('*');

    $scholars->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,MONTH,DAY,scholars.scholar_birthday,CURDATE())'),array($ship_age_from,$ship_age_to));

    $scholars = $scholars->get();


    dd($scholars);
}
```

Error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'scholars.scholar_placebirth,CURDATE()) between ? and ?' at line 1
>   (SQL: select * from `scholars` where
>   TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,MONTH,DAY,scholars.scholar_placebirth,CURDATE())
>   between and )

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ListOrgaScholar($ship_id)
{
    $ship = Scholarship::find($ship_id);
    $ship_age_from = Carbon::now()->subYears($ship->ship_age_from);
    $ship_age_to = Carbon::now()->subYears($ship->ship_age_to);

    $scholars = Scholar::where('scholar_birthday', '>=', $ship_age_from->format('Y-m-d'))->where('scholar_birthday', '<=', $ship_age_to->format('Y-m-d')))->get();
}
```

Comment: Sir this code is not getting the age from database.

Comment: Try this: `$scholars = Scholar::where('scholar_birthday', '>=', $ship_age_from->format('Y-m-d'))->where('scholar_birthday', '<=', $ship_age_to->format('Y-m-d')))->get();`

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry if I forgot to show the sample value of $ship_age_from  and $ship_age_to.These are column names in database.The values would defend on the inputs from the view which directly save under these columns which use for the condition.Example values would be:  ship_age_from = 6, ship_age_to = 12.So in this one line code of mine :$scholars->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,scholars.scholar_birthday,CURDATE())'),array($ship_age_from,$ship_age_to));.

Comment: Con't.:  It calculates the age automatically and if the value falls between the age ship_age_from and ship_age_to ,all matches /rows  will be collected in this line for display:$scholars = $scholars->get();.My problem is the accuracy of the age.The calculation is base only on years not the day.How to correct this line?$scholars->whereBetween(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,scholars.scholar_birthday,CURDATE())'),array($ship_age_from,$ship_age_to));

Comment: @ Alex Lukinov - $scholars = Scholar::where('scholar_birthday', '>=', $ship_age_from->format('Y-m-d'))->where('scholar_birthday', '<=', $ship_age_to->format('Y-m-d')))->get();
    }

This line doesn't calculate the age since the supposed values for ship_age_from and ship_age_to were integers not a date.

Comment: Updated my answer